# When the limits of inequality are given in inequality how to decide from where to where does the limit goes?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

[image: Question]

$0\geq |w|\geq 0.19 \pi$

What does this mean? From where to where does w ranges from?
This is confusing as hell. As it is given w greater 0.19$\pi$ but lesser than 0? How is this possible?

$0.21\pi \leq |w| \leq \pi$

Again here..What does this mean?
does it mean w ranges from -0.21 $\pi$ to $-\pi$ and 0.21$\pi$ to $\pi$?

Comment: $0\geq |w|\geq 0.19 \pi$  looks strange since $|w| \ge 0$ so results in $w=0$.  If you intended $0\leq |w|\leq 0.19 \pi$ and $w$ is real then this is equivalent to: $-0.19 \pi \leq w\leq 0.19 \pi$

Comment: $0.21\pi \leq |w| \leq \pi$ is equivalent to: $-\pi \leq w \leq -0.21\pi$ or $0.21\pi \leq w \leq \pi$

Comment: Oh thanks man. One redditor got me confused. https://old.reddit.com/r/ElectricalEngineering/comments/pi99ls/how_can_w_be_less_than_0_yet_greater_than_019/hbo0tyx/

It is as given in the question(0.19 pi type inequality). I am also confused.